# Super GRUB is not displaying on my external monitor

Tags: display, boot, grub

OK so I have my laptop connected to a TV and I'm running a dual boot with Windows 8.1 and elementary OS Freya.

I open the lid just enough for the power button to work, then I close the lid. Screen goes black, there is no sign of super GRUB, then elementary OS launches by default.

If I unplug the TV and power on, I can see the super grub menu letting me choose which OS to boot on my laptop's display.

If I don't unplug and during the black screen, I move down twice and hit the Return key I can boot Windows.

So super grub is working fine, its just not displaying on my screen. I don't want to be unplugging and plugging the TV every single time, and although blindly moving around the black screen works, I would like too see what I'm doing.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This seems like it is probably a problem upstream with super grub. Does this happen with stock grub? Since this is not included with elementary by default, I think this could be classed as off topic. Perhaps take a google at `nomodeset`.

Comment: I have to disagree with you @LewisGoddard. I think that this question is equivalent to asking about any other software that replaces something that's default in elementary and therefore I think that this should remain open.

Comment: when I installed elementary, I just clicked on the option it gave me to install along with windows. I didn't partition the disk myself or anything. (I assumed it was grub) but whatever is allowing me to select the OS, came with the elementary ISO. I will look into the nomodeset. Thank you.

Comment: @aaeim is this still an issue? I think perhaps it should be closed.